# Error in RecyclerViewAdapter's onBindViewHolder() Method

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

Guys it could seems similar to you like other NullPionterException Questions and before mark it as duplicate please read it and try to understand my problem first and point it out where i am wrong.

Actually my app is accessing some JOSN data then parse it and make a POJO object and put that object in some `ArrayList<SchemesHitsPojoModel> schemesListHitsWise` then i send this ArrayList to my RecyclerViewAdapter Class and then displaying it in RecyclerView.

But inside my `onBindViewHolder` method when i try to set some text on schemeName then it gives me following error. Help me guys i am trying to resolve this problem form last couple of days and read lots of answers but still this error remains.

**LogCat**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.dovezeal.gapp.adapters.HitsOnSchemesDataDisplayAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HitsOnSchemesDataDisplayAdapter.java:71)
            at com.dovezeal.gapp.adapters.HitsOnSchemesDataDisplayAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HitsOnSchemesDataDisplayAdapter.java:21)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5277)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5310)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4568)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1371)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at c
```

**MyAdapter File**

```
 @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = null;
        MyViewHolder viewHolder;
        switch (success){
            case(0):
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_no_record_found_msg_screen, parent, false);
                break;
            case(1):
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_recyclerview_row_each_scheme_hits, parent,false);

        }
        viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SchemesHitsPojoModel firstObject = schemesListHitsWise.get(0);
        success = firstObject.getSuccess();
        if(success == 0 ){
            Log.d("SORRY!, "," We don't have any records to show you.");
        }
        else{
            SchemesHitsPojoModel currentSchemeRow =  schemesListHitsWise.get(position);
            holder.schemeName.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeName());
            int langId = currentSchemeRow.getLanguage_id();
            switch(langId){
                case(1):
                    holder.languageName.setText("Punjabi");
                    break;
                case(2):
                    holder.languageName.setText("English");
            }

            holder.schemeViewDate.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeViewDate());
            holder.schemeHits.setText(String.valueOf(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeHits()));
            holder.viewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_red_eye_black_18dp);
            //holder.totalHitsOnThisScheme.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeTotalHitsCount());
        }
    }

// MyViewHolder
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView schemeName, schemeViewDate, languageName, schemeHits,totalHitsOnThisScheme;
        ImageView viewIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            schemeName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnSchemeName);
            languageName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnLangName);
            viewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnViewIcon);
            schemeViewDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnSchemeViewDate);
            schemeHits = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnSchemeHits);
            //totalHitsOnThisScheme = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalHitsOnThisScheme);
        }
    }
```

**XML File of RecyclerView's Custom Row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hitsOnSchemeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:width="270dp"
            android:text="Name of the Scheme"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hitsOnViewIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_18dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hitsOnSchemeHits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:text="5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hitsOnLangName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:width="270dp"
            android:text="Language of scheme"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hitsOnSchemeViewDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:text="1989-12-09"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is classic NPE.

Comment: Maybe you are inflating the wrong view in onCreateViewHolder(). Make sure you're not returning null from that function.

Comment: Your errors are in your adapter class, on the lines 71 and 21. Check them, check your xml file. Please use the debugging options and go through your code step by step.

Comment: @ankitagrawal  success is a variable that store the int value (Zero or one) for JSON request if the JSON Request is successfull and returned any data the it has he value 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh thanks bro you just saved my life and yes it was my silly mistake. please read my answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Thank you guys and i really appreciate your help. Actually it was my bad.

I was storing the value to `success` variable inside my `onBindViewHolder()` which is going to be used for inside both method (onCreateViewHolder(), onBindViewHolder() ) and that was my actual mistake

because i forgot that i am using this `success` variable in my `onCreateViewHolder()` as well to select my particular layout for particular situation and because of that mistake when my `onCtreatViewHolder()` runs, at that time `success=0` and it returns the wrong layout.

Now the bottom line is this,

1. I Create the Global variable named as `success`
2. and inside `onCreateViewHolder()` Method i store the value for `success`
3. then, i use this `success` variable for my both methods

here is my solution that is working fine currently.

```
 private int success;

    // Constructor
    public HitsOnSchemesDataDisplayAdapter(Context context){
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setSchemesListHitsWise(ArrayList<SchemesHitsPojoModel> schemesListHitsWise){
        this.schemesListHitsWise = schemesListHitsWise;
        notifyItemRangeChanged(0, schemesListHitsWise.size());
    }
```

**onCreateViewHolder() Method**

```
@Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = null;
        MyViewHolder viewHolder;
        SchemesHitsPojoModel firstObject = schemesListHitsWise.get(0);
        success = firstObject.getSuccess();
        switch (success){
            case(0):
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_no_record_found_msg_screen, parent, false);
                Log.d("VIEW "," is runned....");
                break;
            case(1):
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_recyclerview_row_each_scheme_hits, parent,false);
                Log.d("VIEW_2, "," is run....");
                break;

            default:
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_no_record_found_msg_screen, parent, false);
                break;
        }
        viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
```

**onBindViewHolder() Method**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SchemesHitsPojoModel firstObject = schemesListHitsWise.get(0);
        //int success = firstObject.getSuccess();
        if(success == 0 ){
            Log.d("SORRY!, "," We don't have any records to show you.");
        }
        else if(success == 1){
            SchemesHitsPojoModel currentSchemeRow =  schemesListHitsWise.get(position);
            holder.schemeName.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeName());
            int langId = currentSchemeRow.getLanguage_id();
            switch(langId){
                case(1):
                    holder.languageName.setText("Punjabi");
                    break;
                case(2):
                    holder.languageName.setText("English");
            }

            holder.schemeViewDate.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeViewDate());
            holder.schemeHits.setText(String.valueOf(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeHits()));
            holder.viewIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_red_eye_black_18dp);
            //holder.totalHitsOnThisScheme.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeTotalHitsCount());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you problem is here

```
holder.schemeName.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeName());
```

change this to

`holder.schemeName.setText(currentSchemeRow.get(position).getSchemeName()`);

move

```
SchemesHitsPojoModel currentSchemeRow =  schemesListHitsWise.get(position);
```

out of else method

Comment: that move is important

Answer (score 0):

You need to change,

There are two chances to get this ERROR.

1.Change your

```
holder.schemeViewDate.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeViewDate());
holder.schemeHits.setText(String.valueOf(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeHits()));
```

TO

```
   holder.schemeViewDate.setText(currentSchemeRow.get(position).getSchemeViewDate());
   holder.schemeHits.setText("" + currentSchemeRow..get(position).getSchemeHits());
```

**currentSchemeRow should be Arraylist of your model where you have get and set data,** and you have to get value from **get(position)** that is your selected position.

2. Might have used the wrong id's OR have not declared any from both of layout files that is **custom_recyclerview_row_each_scheme_hits** OR **custom_no_record_found_msg_screen**

---

```
schemeName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnSchemeName);    
 languageName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnLangName);    
 viewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnViewIcon);    
 schemeViewDate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnSchemeViewDate); 
 schemeHits = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hitsOnSchemeHits);
```

Comment: My already have my arrayList and this is it `ArrayList<SchemesHitsPojoModel> schemesListHitsWise` and it contain the my POJO objects (if JSON Req returns the any) and success(1 in this case) so i already got that object here-->`SchemesHitsPojoModel currentSchemeRow =  schemesListHitsWise.get(position);`  so now currentSchemeRow is my current Object and after that i am getting the data from that object and setting it on a string `holder.schemeName.setText(currentSchemeRow.getSchemeName());`..... tell me bro you are the expert here , am i right or not ??

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in onCreateViewHolder

```
    switch (success){
        case(0):
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_no_record_found_msg_screen, parent, false);
            break;
        case(1):
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_recyclerview_row_each_scheme_hits, parent,false);
```

here you inflating two different layouts so your all TexViews must be present in both layouts .

OR

place an if condition in onBindViewHolder to handle the null pointer exception because onBindViewHolder must be called in both cases.